# Collection Framework :Collection View vs Actual Collection For Iteration

Tags: java, collections

I want to understand why we need Collection Views to Iterate through the Java Collections. Why actual Collection is not used for Iteration. I understand that Views are referencing to the actual Backed Collection and its just a light weight Object. Are there any Advantages, any Design decisions.

Comment: What views are you talking about? There's no views for iterating lists and sets.

Comment: In Map, keySet, entrySet, Values are such examples. Please throw some light on the above. If I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your question says "Collection". The Java [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) is an interface representing a collection of values. Notable sub-interfaces are [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), and [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), just to mention a few. The `Collection` interface is an extension of [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), and can as such be iterated.

The Java [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is an interface representing mappings of keys to values. It is **NOT** a sub-interface of `Collection`, although it is part of the [Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) of Java. It does *not* extend `Iterable`, and can not be iterated directly.

Since a `Map` consists of key/value pairs, it provides methods for iterating the map in 3 ways. You can iterate the *keys*, you can iterate the *values*, and you can iterate the key/value *pairs*, using `keySet()`, `values()`, and `entrySet()`, respectively.

These are the "views" you are referring to, and they are needed because a `Map` is not a `Collection` and is not `Iterable`.

Please be more clear next time you ask a question, because all the `Collection` interfaces and classes do not need a view to iterate them. As such, your question *"why we need Collection Views to Iterate through the Java Collections"* is meaningless.

Comment: I'm going through the following link related to views  have a look at it. http://softwarecave.org/2014/03/19/views-in-java-collections-framework/, May be you will get better idea what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: Your question was about why we need views to iterate collections? We *don't*. That link, which would have explained a lot of your confusion if it had been in the question, is about creating collection views of non-collections, and creating views of *part* of a collection. Your question goes on "Why actual Collection is not used for Iteration". What *actual* collection are you referring to?